Hibernate ConstraintViolationException on SELECT query because of cached INSERT statement
I have this Hibernate select query that gives me a ConstraintViolationException.
Method:
public RfaSchoolWorkflow findViaCasePrepForm(CasePrepForm model) {
    TypedQuery<RfaSchoolWorkflow> query = createQuery("select rfa from RfaSchoolWorkflow rfa where rfa.schoolCasePrepForm.casePrepForm = :cpf");
    query.setParameter("cpf", model);
   
    return QueryUtil.single(query);
}

Exception:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."TABLE_B"."ID")

There is no trigger on this query, how can a SELECT query return a ConstraintViolationException?
Here I read that this might be because Hibernate cached a previously created statement but for some reason not yet executed insert statement. Before executing my SELECT statement Hibernate then somehow sees the need to execute the cached INSERT statement. The execution of the INSERT results in a ConstraintViolationException which is why the program doesn't get the change to execute my SELECT.
Also here people seem to have a similar problem.
I've looked everywhere in the code, but I can't find anything that could try to insert data into TABLE_A. Is there a way to keep hibernate from executing statements in the cache and hence solve the problem?
Full stack trace:
09:17:33.042 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] ERROR a.e.w.e.b.d.RfaStudentWorkflowDaoImpl - An error occurred while finding RfaStudentWorkflow for CasePrepForm: CasePrepForm:343014
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1626) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.guice.util.QueryUtil.single(QueryUtil.java:78) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.bes.dao.RfaStudentWorkflowDaoImpl.findViaCasePrepForm(RfaStudentWorkflowDaoImpl.java:346) ~[bes-server-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.bes.service.RfaStudentWorkflowServiceImpl.findViaCasePrepForm(RfaStudentWorkflowServiceImpl.java:64) ~[bes-server-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.bes.service.accesscontrol.CasePrepFormAccessControlServiceImpl.getDelegate(CasePrepFormAccessControlServiceImpl.java:114) ~[bes-server-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.bes.service.accesscontrol.CasePrepFormAccessControlServiceImpl.canRead(CasePrepFormAccessControlServiceImpl.java:74) ~[bes-server-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.bes.service.accesscontrol.CasePrepFormAccessControlServiceImpl.canRead(CasePrepFormAccessControlServiceImpl.java:19) ~[bes-server-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.guice.service.ExternalIdManagerImpl.checkReadAccess(ExternalIdManagerImpl.java:587) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.guice.service.ExternalIdManagerImpl.decodePublicId(ExternalIdManagerImpl.java:122) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.guice.service.ExternalIdManagerImpl.decodeKey(ExternalIdManagerImpl.java:65) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.guice.resolver.PersistentEntityResolver.getModel(PersistentEntityResolver.java:82) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.guice.resolver.PersistentEntityResolver.getModel(PersistentEntityResolver.java:12) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.guice.mapper.AbstractCommonModelMapper.getModel(AbstractCommonModelMapper.java:133) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.guice.mapper.AbstractCommonModelMapper.applyToModel(AbstractCommonModelMapper.java:142) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.bes.mapper.RfaStudentWfModelMapper.populateModelFields(RfaStudentWfModelMapper.java:161) ~[bes-server-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.bes.mapper.RfaStudentWfModelMapper.populateModelFields(RfaStudentWfModelMapper.java:35) ~[bes-server-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.ssta.mapper.AbstractAuditedEntityModelMapper.populateModel(AbstractAuditedEntityModelMapper.java:123) ~[bes-server-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.ssta.mapper.AbstractAuditedEntityModelMapper.populateModel(AbstractAuditedEntityModelMapper.java:25) ~[bes-server-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.guice.mapper.AbstractCommonModelMapper.applyToModel(AbstractCommonModelMapper.java:153) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.guice.mapper.AbstractCommonModelMapper.applyToModel(AbstractCommonModelMapper.java:94) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.bes.gwtservice.RfaStudentServiceImpl$SaveProcessor.prepare(RfaStudentServiceImpl.java:229) ~[bes-server-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.bes.gwtservice.RfaStudentServiceImpl.saveStudentRfa(RfaStudentServiceImpl.java:493) ~[bes-server-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.bes.gwtservice.RfaStudentServiceImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$68491dc5.CGLIB$saveStudentRfa$6(<generated>) ~[bes-server-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.bes.gwtservice.RfaStudentServiceImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$68491dc5$$FastClassByGuice$$50bbf3ee.invoke(<generated>) ~[bes-server-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[guice-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:76) ~[guice-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.guice.GwtServiceMethodInterceptor.invoke(GwtServiceMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:78) ~[guice-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:54) ~[guice-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.bes.gwtservice.RfaStudentServiceImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$68491dc5.saveStudentRfa(<generated>) ~[bes-server-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587) ~[gwt-servlet-2.10.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:333) ~[gwt-servlet-2.10.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:303) ~[gwt-servlet-2.10.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373) ~[gwt-servlet-2.10.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62) ~[gwt-servlet-2.10.0.jar:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555) ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623) ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:290) ~[guice-servlet-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:280) ~[guice-servlet-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:184) ~[guice-servlet-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:89) ~[guice-servlet-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85) ~[guice-servlet-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.filter.IndexPageCacheFilter.doFilter(IndexPageCacheFilter.java:39) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) ~[guice-servlet-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.guice.UserNameScopingFilter.doFilter(UserNameScopingFilter.java:33) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) ~[guice-servlet-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.filter.GwtCacheFilter.doFilter(GwtCacheFilter.java:121) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) ~[guice-servlet-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.filter.AjaxSecurityFilter.doFilter(AjaxSecurityFilter.java:59) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) ~[guice-servlet-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.filter.BookmarkFilter.doFilter(BookmarkFilter.java:58) ~[gwt-guice-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) ~[guice-servlet-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.common.hibernate.HibernateFilter.doFilter(HibernateFilter.java:187) ~[common-hibernate-core-3.0.36-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) ~[guice-servlet-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.appreg.impl.SecurityFilterImpl.doSecurityFilter(SecurityFilterImpl.java:557) ~[?:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.appreg.servlet.SecurityFilter.doHttpFilterChain(SecurityFilter.java:99) ~[appreg-client-2.6.1.jar:?]
    at com.gsu.de.eddept.appreg.client.error.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) ~[appreg-client-2.6.1.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) ~[guice-servlet-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:121) ~[guice-servlet-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:133) ~[guice-servlet-4.2.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.81]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.81]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1367) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1447) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    ... 83 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."TABLE_B"."ID")

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:628) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:562) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1145) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:726) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:291) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:492) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:148) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1038) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLStatement(OracleStatement.java:1507) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1287) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3735) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3910) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3889) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:992) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1502) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1367) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1447) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
    ... 83 more


Can you post the exceptions stacktrace?

@Scary Wombat Done :)

I would guess that the after cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."TABLE_B"."ID") the transaction is not being rollback'd / terminated correctly.

I think your issue has to do with the flush mode being used by Hibernate (see  the flush documentation. Quoting part of the docs:

From time to time, a flush operation is triggered, and the session synchronizes dirty state held in memory—that is, modifications to the state of entities associated with the persistence context—with persistent state held in the database. Of course, it does this by executing SQL INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.
By default, a flush is triggered:
when the current transaction commits, for example, when
Transaction.commit() is called,
before execution of a query whose result would be affected by the
synchronization of dirty state held in memory, or
when the program directly calls flush().

You can control the flush mode, but I think the defaults are normally fine. I think your issue is caused by a call to persist, save or merge that violates the id constraint. You are somehow missing to set the id for table TABLE_B and I guess is that your entity is not configured to use autogeneration of the id (see generation strategies). Without the source code is all guesses of course.
